# What's the correct way to process all the payload of a sk_buff packet in Linux

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel, skb

I'm currently trying to debug an ATM encapsulation layer that runs on-top of Ethernet. Basically the ATM cells are stored in order after the ethernet header. However I suspect the drivers naive approach to the sk_buffs is broken.

The driver blindly assumes that skb->data can be iterated through but looking at the kernel code for virtio_net.c:page_to_skb I see the following behaviour:

```
memcpy(hdr, p, hdr_len);
len -= hdr_len;
p += offset;
copy = len;

if (copy > skb_tailroom(skb))
        copy = skb_tailroom(skb);

memcpy(skb_put(skb, copy), p, copy);
```

Then further on:

```
while (len) {
        set_skb_frag(skb, page, offset, &len);
    page = (struct page *)page->private;
    offset = 0;
}
```

Which seems to show the buffer is fragmented with only the first portion being directly accessible from skb->data.

What should I be using to get at the underlying data. Ideally I want to peek a few bytes at arbitrary offsets into the ethernet packet before memcpy'ing chunks into a reassembly buffer I maintain. What should I be using to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The implementation of socket buffers are comprised of a linear data buffer and one or more page buffers.

The existence of paged data in a socket buffer is indicated by `skb->data_len` member being non-zero.

`bool skb_is_nonlinear(const struct sk_buff *skb)` defined in `/include/linux/skbuff.h` is used to test this.

The amount of non-paged data at skb->data can be calculated as skb->len - skb->data_len. 
`unsigned int skb_headlen(const struct sk_buff *skb)` defined in `/include/linux/skbuff.h` is used to test this.

The `skb->data` pointer only points to the non paged data, which what the driver you described possibly relies on.

`void *skb_header_pointer(const struct sk_buff *skb, int offset, int len, void *buffer)` is defined in `/include/linux/skbuff.h` . It takes the socket buffer, byte offset and byte length your want 
and a local data buffer which is only used if the data is in one of the page buffers.

It returns a pointer to either the data in the linear data buffer from `skb->data` or the pointer to the local data buffer supplied,
or NULL if your offset and length were incorrect.

For pieces of data larger than protocol headers you either want to use

`int skb_copy_bits(const struct sk_buff *skb, int offset,void *to, int len);`

to copy from a given socket buffer ,byte offset and byte length to a given kernel buffer.

or

`int skb_copy_datagram_iovec(const struct sk_buff *from, int offset, struct iovec *to, int size);`

to to copy from a given socket buffer ,byte offset and byte length to a given iovec structure in user space.

Examples of usage can been seen in netfilter code and in other Ethernet drivers.

**For further information**

- [Socket Buffer Introduction by David S. Miller](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html)
- [Socket Buffer Data Layout by David S. Miller](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_data.html)
- [Socket Buffer Tutorial by Roberto Innocente, O.S.Adewale](http://people.sissa.it/~inno/pubs/skb-reduced.pdf)