# Functions for getting packet headers available in sk_buff

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, udp

There are functions in Linux for getting Ethernet header, IP header,and UDP headers likes these

```
udp_hdr(skb)
ip_hdr
skb_push(skb, ETH_HLEN)
```

But I could not find any function for getting payload like body of a packet like i.e. which contains body  so I can write  HTTP or other protocol data. in Linux Device Driver book or after searching couldn't find it. so question is how to compose UDP packet with Ethernet, IP, UDP headers and payload in kernel?

Comment: skb is object of socket buffer

Comment: did you not see skb->data?

Comment: @user253751 so I only need to use skb->data for payload? What data type will be on the variable on the left side of `=` like `char *payloadhtml=skb->data` will it work?

Comment: @user253751 And how to get the size of `payloadhtml` in my last comment which will be required to read payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any function for getting payload like body of a packet

You can access payload different ways depending on what you want to do the next time. E.g.:

```
struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);

if (iph->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
    struct udphdr *udph = udp_hdr(skb);
    // E.g. check for UDP port
    struct myl7_header *l7h = (struct myl7_header *)(udph + sizeof(struct udphdr));
    // ...
}
```

---

Or you can pull the network and transport headers if you want to reconstruct encapsulation further or they are no longer needed (rough example, not with all possible sanity checks):

```
struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);

if (iph->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
    struct udphdr *udph = udp_hdr(skb);
    struct myl7_header *l7h;
    // E.g. check for UDP port
    skb_pull(skb, sizeof(struct iphdr));
    skb_pull(skb, sizeof(struct udphdr));
    l7h = (struct myl7_header *)skb->data;
    // tansport protocol payload's length:
    // skb->len or skb_tail_pointer(skb) - skb->data
}
```

I don't really know what you mean by `payloadhtml`, L7-protocol it not so kernel specific thing, so in general we are talking about transport protocol's payload.

N.B.: `ip_hdr()`, `udp_hdr()` functions imply that non-paged (linear) skb is used.

Related: [What's the correct way to process all the payload of a sk_buff packet in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588639/whats-the-correct-way-to-process-all-the-payload-of-a-sk-buff-packet-in-linux)

Comment: Instead of struct in ur example like `struct myl7_header *l7h = (struct myl7_header *)(udph + sizeof(struct udphdr))`. Will `char *my100_header  = (char *)(udph + sizeof(struct udphdr))` will this also work? If i like to read 100 characters from `char *myl7_header`?